# select the first visible cell after heading and after filter has been applied in CSV file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying from Excel through VBA to open a CSV file, filter it and check the first cell in column J after heading is empty or not.
This is the code so far

```
With wsDest
Sheets("ClustersBU").Range("$a$1:$j$1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=idevent

Sheets("ClustersBU").Range("a" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) (1).Row).Select
End with
```

The first line filters the CSV file properly, the second line keeps giving me an error:
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
I tried different solutions but nothing works and since I am not a vba expert I thought to ask for help.

Thank you,

Comment: `Offset` is a property of a range, not a worksheet.

Comment: Maybe try like this : `With wsDest.Sheets("ClustersBU")` ... next line `.Range("$a$1:$j$1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=idevent` ... next line `With .AutoFilter.Range` ... next line `.Range("a" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) (1).Row).Select` ... next line `end with` ... next line `end with`. Then I think it will select the first visible cell in column A.

Comment: Thanks Karma, for finding the time to post a solution to try out.
I solved the problem using a different approach, I will post the solution shortly

Answer (score 0):

It seems I managed to solve this problem "from the bottom" instead of "from the top".
I will post the solution in case somebody else has the same need.

```
 Sub Import_Cluster_External()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim data As Range
Dim wsDest, wsMain As Workbook

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook

idevent = xyz

Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users...\***.CSV")

            With wsDest
            Sheets("ClustersBU").Range("$a$1:$k$1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=idevent
                
            lastRow = Sheets("ClustersBU").Cells(Sheets("ClustersBU").Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
            ideventcheck = Range("k" & lastRow)
                
            If ideventcheck = idevent Then
            MsgBox "clusters found"
                                   
            Else
            MsgBox "Clusters not found "
                    
            End If
            End With
            wsDest.Close (False)
   
End Sub
```

Hope you will find it useful.

Cheers!